How to create bulk users with email in Azure's user CSV
I'm trying to create batch users in Azure via portal.azure.com.
I can download the example CSV from Azure, fill it out, and upload it successfully.
However, I now want to add an email address for each user entry.
Is this possible?
One of the approved columns in the example CSV is User name [userPrincipalName] Required, which is in an email-like format, such as chris@contoso.com. From my understanding, while userPrincipalName uses an "email-like" format, it doesn’t have to resolve to an actual email address.
I want to batch-add email addresses alongside user entries. How can I achieve this?
Here’s a screenshot of my attempt to add mail as a new column, which resulted in an error. I also tried using Email, but that failed as well.


I took a look at the CSV Template in the Azure portal and none of the columns are for email - so there doesn't seem to be a way to do this using the Bulk/CSV feature - you'd have to do it by scripting against the MS Graph API using a tool like Postman or Linqpad.

@RonPringadi Any update?

Please click on checkmark beside the answer if it's helpful for you in any way

When creating bulk users using the CSV file, the allowed columns are limited to those specified by Azure. The mail or Email columns are not natively supported for user creation through this method.
Initially, I too got same error when I tried to include mail column in CSV file for bulk user creation:

Alternatively, you can make use of Microsoft Graph or PowerShell to achieve your scenario as suggested by @Dai.
Initially, I uploaded CSV file having sample set of user's data without ading extra field like mail in it:

This created new users without Email field data like this:

Now, I created one csv file in this format including user's UserPrincipalName and Mail:
UserPrincipalName,Mail
sampleuser01@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com,sampleuser1@domain.com
sampleuser02@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com,sampleuser2@domain.com
sampleuser03@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com,sampleuser3@domain.com
sampleuser04@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com,sampleuser4@domain.com
sampleuser05@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com,sampleuser5@domain.com

To update Email field of all those sample users, I used below Microsoft Graph PowerShell script:
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.ReadWrite.All"

$csvPath = "C:\path\to\users.csv"
$users = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

foreach ($user in $users) {
    try {
        $userId = (Get-MgUser -UserId $user.UserPrincipalName).Id
        Update-MgUser -UserId $userId -Mail $user.Mail
        Write-Host "Updated mail for user $($user.UserPrincipalName)" -ForegroundColor Green
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Failed to update mail for user $($user.UserPrincipalName): $_" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}

Response:

When I checked the same in Portal, Email property updated successfully for all sample set of users like this:

